# Construction of a set-valued correspondence and upper semicontinuity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Consider a bounded function $f:A\to B$ where $A\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is compact and $B\subset \mathbb{R}^d$.
Suppose that $f$ is discontinuous on some hyperplanes and that it can be written as
$$
f(x) = F(x, u_1(x), \ldots, u_m(x))
$$
where
$F:A\times [0,1]^m \to B$ is continuous in its arguments and
$u_i(x)=1_{\{\phi_i(x)=0\}}\in \{0,1\}$, with $\phi_i(x)$ linear and $1_{\{\cdot\}}$ denoting the indicator function.

Now, I want to build a set-valued correspondence $G$ with the following properties:

a) if $x$ is a continuity point of $f$, then $G(x)=f(x)$.

b) if $x$ is a discontinuity point of $f$, then $G(x)$ is the smallest convex closed set containing all the limit values of $f(x^*)$ for $x^*\notin M$ and $x^*\to x$, where $M$ is a set of measure zero consisting of all the boundary points of the hyperplanes $\phi_i(x)=0$.

So, it's not really clear to me what $G(x)$ is at a discontinuity point, but here it is my guess:
if $\phi_1(x)=\cdots = \phi_k(x) =0$ and $\phi_{j}(x)\neq  0$ for all $j=k+1,\ldots,m$, then
$$
G(x) = \{ F(x, y_1,\ldots,y_k,u_{k+1}(x), \ldots, u_m(x)) : y_i\in [0,1], \,\forall i=1,\ldots,k \}
$$

Questions:

1) Am I correct? If not, how can I write down $G(x)$?

2) Can I deduce that $G(x)$ is upper semicontinuous?